# Is there any way to use the Electronic Drum Kits as regular midi drum kits (instead of as summing stacks) in Logic Pro X?

Tags: logic-pro

I have created a MIDI script that I use for the standard drum kits that come from Logic Pro X, eg. "Blue Ridge" or "Bluebird".

[image]

However, I cannot use this script against the electronic drum kits (e.g. "808 Flex" or "Above and Beyond") as those are showing up as "DMD" and do not have the option to add MIDI controls.

[image]

Is there any way to use the MIDI controls, such as Scripter, Modifier, Modulator, etc, on an Electronic Drum Kit like I can on the regular Drum Kits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What is Drum Machine Designer (DMD)?

Drum Machine Designer (DMD) is basically a [Summing Stack](https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/logicpro/lgcp9bc4b63d/mac) with a grid/pad interface, with each pad mapped to a track in the track stack which gets triggered by a note (C1, C#1, D1...) designated on respective pads.

[image]
So for 808 Flex :
key C1 is mapped to Kick 1 which is a sample named Kick_1_808Flex.aif loaded in the first pad as a One Shot Sampler instrument.

If DMD is record enabled and key C1 is pressed on a MIDI keyboard then the corresponding track hosting Sampler (Kick 1) gets activated and a particular note, which you can define as the Root Key in the bottom left corner of the sampler interface, gets played.

### Is there any way to use the MIDI FX

As the MIDI FX slot for DMD is unavailable so it's fairly obvious that as of ver 10.7.2 it is not (directly) possible to use MIDI FX on a DMD.

Side note : DMD is controlling multiple instruments and each grid/pad is a software instrument track, with a dedicated channel strip in the mixer, which takes MIDI input and hence can be manipulated individually by MIDI FX.

[image]

### Is there any workaround?

Yes.

- Load an External Instrument in another track
- Choose '[IAC Driver Bus](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8096575)' from the MIDI Destination dropdown
- Leave every other option as it is
  [image]
- Make sure the MIDI In Port of DMD is set to 'All'

[image]

- Record Enable the External Instrument track and record your MIDI.
- After you're done, 'Record Enable' DMD and play recorded MIDI region from the start, DMD will playback the MIDI.
- As 'External Instrument' has MIDI FX slot, you can put any MIDI FX on it and DMD will play it back

[image]

Caveat : Only recorded MIDI will work, you cannot live-record it.

---

Reference Logic Pro ver : 10.7.2

Comment: The workaround looks awesome, I will try it. THANK YOU!

Comment: I don't know bout v10.7.2, but in 10.5.1 there's an easy workaround. You assign one of the sampled drummer kits that allows MIDI scripts to the channel, turn on patch merging and set it to merge only the instruments, and then select one of the DMD kits.